# I'd like to know the relations among openmax, directshow and ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

- I wonder if openmax is for linux as directshow is for windows.
- I wonder if openmax and directshow have same purpose.
- I wonder if openmax proivdes hw decoding to ffmpeg in linux as direct show provides hw decoding to ffmpeg in windows.
- In short I'd like to know basic relations among those - openmax, directshow and ffmpeg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [OpenMax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMAX) is an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API) specification
- [DirectShow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectShow) is an API specification and an implementation of that API
- [FFmpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg) provides libraries, and libraries are implementations of API specifications

### Is openmax for linux as directshow is for windows?

No. OpenMax is a cross-platform API.  Noone has seen it on Windows, but theoretically one could implement the OpenMAX API on Windows.

### Do openmax and directshow have the same purpose?

Considering both as APIs, yes, since both address multimedia.

### Does openmax provide hardware decoding to ffmpeg in linux as DirectShow provides hw decoding to ffmpeg in windows?

The issue of hardware support is independent of all three APIs.  Though OpenMax is mainly used to expose hardware for multimedia acceleration under Linux, but one could very well implement an OpenMax API partially or fully in software (and on other platforms).  DirectShow has filters that are implemented completely in software and others that expose hardware.  Same can be said about ffmpeg [encoders, decoders](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html) and [filters](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html): some use hardware (see [QSV encoders](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#QSV-encoders), [OpenCL Video filters](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#OpenCL-Video-Filters) - but then again OpenCl might be realized in partially or completely software), most are software only.